# Counting how many items are repeated 1, 2 or 3 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have values

```
Contractor_Key
--
AAA
BBB
CCC
BBB
CCC
CCC
DDD
CCC
```

In this example, AAA and DDD repeated just once, this means that count of once repeated values is 2. BBB repeated twice and twice repeated items count here is just 1.
exactly tree times repeated values there are not at all and I don't want  output CCC because it repeated more than 3 times.

I need calculate, how many values I have, which repeated exactly once, twice or three times.

I know this is something by using grouping, but don't realize how to get desirable result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT item_repeated_quantity, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT  Contractor_Key, COUNT(*) AS item_repeated_quantity from t group by Contractor_Key HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
)t
GROUP BY  item_repeated_quantity
ORDER BY item_repeated_quantity
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you very much. Thanks to all

Answer (score 6):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(Contractor_Key), max(Contractor_Key)
from (select Contractor_Key, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by Contractor_Key
     ) c
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

I call this a "histogram-of-histgrams" query.  I include two examples of keys for each count for further investigation.

Comment: No TESS records found.  For a nominal fee, you can Trademark "Histogram-of-Histgrams"    +1

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do aggregation twice - first to find count for each contractor_key and then find count for each value of count (found in first aggregation):

```
select cnt,
    count(*) as times
from (
    select count(*) cnt
    from your_table
    group by contractor_key
    ) t
group by cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Contractor_Key,
        Cnt  = COUNT(1)
        FROM MyTable
            GROUP BY Contractor_Key
)
SELECT
    Cnt,
    COUNT(1)
    FROM CTE
```